# Find Distinct record in a table where source and destination are same

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with column source an destination want to find only distinct record from table where source and destination are same

```
Create table test (id int, sources varchar(50), destination varchar(50))


Insert into test(id, sources,destination)
select 1,'delhi', 'mumbai'
union all
select 2,'mumbai','delhi'
union all
select 3, 'delhi', 'nagpur'
union all
select 4, 'lucknow', 'bhopal'
union all
select 5, 'bhopal','lucknow'
```

Comment: Can you please add output you want?

Comment: Hi Uttam, 
thank you for reply.

Comment: I want out put like

Comment: id   sources        destination 
1    delhi          mumbai
3    delhi          nagpur
4    bhopal         lucknow

Comment: I guess 1 and 2 are same, and 4 and 5 too, right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

select * from test t
left join test p on t.sources=p.destination and t.destination=p.sources 
where t.sources > p.sources or p.sources is null

Comment: Can you please let me know-how the where clause (  t.sources > p.sources) works here.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.source, a.destination from test a, test b
   where a.destination = b.destination and
         a.source = b.source and
         a.id <> b.id
```

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please also add a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
SELECT
  sources,
  destination
FROM test a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT
  *
FROM test a1
WHERE a1.destination = a.sources
AND a1.sources = a.destination
AND a1.sources > a.sources)
AND (sources != destination)
UNION
SELECT
  sources,
  destination
FROM test a
WHERE sources = destination
AND ((SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM test
WHERE sources = a.sources
AND destination = a.sources)
> 1)
ORDER BY sources;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it?

```
Select distinct source, destination 
into #temp
from test

delete a
from  #temp a, #temp b
where a.source = b.destination
and b.source = a.destination

Select a.id, a.source,b.destination
from test a,#temp b
where a.source = b.source
and a.destination =b.destination

drop table #temp
```